# siblings() error: InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have an error in symfony2 unit testing , symfony : 2.7.1

```
when I use siblings() I have a the error:
```

InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.
the twig file:

```
<h1>ddd</h1>

<p>ahmedghgh</p>

<ul>
    <li>dddd</li>
    <li>eeee</li>
    <li>ffff</li>    
</ul>

</p>bye</p>

<form action ="" method="GET" name ="nameForm">
    <input type="text" value ="name" name="name">
     <input type="submit" value ="send" name="send">

</form>
```

BasicControllerTest.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace TestingSymfony\BasicBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class BasicControllerTest extends WebTestCase {

    public function testHelloContent() {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/helloworld');
        $h1 = $crawler->filter('h1')->eq(0);
        $p1 = $crawler->filter('p')->first();


        $ul = $p1->siblings()->eq(0);        
        $l1 = $ul->children()->first();
        $l2 = $ul->children()->eq(1);
        $l3 = $ul->children()->last();

        $p2 = $crawler->filterXPath("//p")->last();
    }
}
```

Once I remove the siblings , all is ok and no error appeared

Comment: Hi, I try to replicate the problem but in my env i don't have any error!

Comment: what is ur symfony version ?

Comment: sf 2.7.1 and PHPUnit 4.3.5

Comment: with older version of the framework I have some problem with not valid html that i post in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the twig files: check that the P tag is open and closed correclty, as follow:

```
<p>bye</p>
```

instead of

```
</p>bye</p>
```

Hope this help

Comment: thanks , it is solved as u said + 
change to
$ul = $p1->siblings()->eq(1);

Answer (score 0):

Your `filter`did not return any results as you had a typo. That is why it crashed. However, for others who did not have any typo, that's how I solved this issue, by adding a try catch.

```
try {
   $p1 = $crawler->filter('p')->first();
} catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    // Handle the current node list is empty..
}
```